# Adding attribute to a feature type?

Tags: java, geotools

I need to do something apparently simple: adding a new attribute to an existing simple feature type. Something like:

```
SimpleFeatureType sft = DataUtilities.createType("", "the_geom:Point:srid=3035,ex:String,nb:int");

sft.addAttribute("newAttribute", String.class);
```

There is unfortunatelly no such **addAttribute** method and I did not find any direct way, or even a work around. The class **DataUtilities** allows a number of operations on feature types, but not that one. Maybe it is not possible. Does anybody has an idea how such operation could be performed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FeatureType`s are immutable, so you can't change them, it makes life much simpler if you can assume a features attributes will not change during its lifetime.

To add an attribute you first need to create a new `FeatureType` based on the old one and then call [`DataUtilities.reType(..)`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/DataUtilities.html#reType-org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType-org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature-) to modify your existing features to new schema.

Something like:

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder ftBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
SimpleFeatureType schema = collection.getSchema();
ftBuilder.setName(schema.getName());
ftBuilder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
ftBuilder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());
// add new attribute(s)
ftBuilder.add("colour", Integer.class);
// build new schema
nSchema = ftBuilder.buildFeatureType();
List<SimpleFeature> newFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collection.features()) {

  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
    SimpleFeature nF = DataUtilities.reType(nSchema, f);
    nF.setAttribute("colour", color);
    newFeatures.add(nF);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !